# UIAutomation in PowerShell is slow accessing UI elements

Tags: powershell, ui-automation

I am having an issue using the UIAutomation package for PowerShell (https://uiautomation.codeplex.com/) where it is extremely slow trying to access a UI element when the application I am using it on has many UI elements. I have tried the script I used on the same application that loads fewer UI elements and it runs faster. Is there a way to have the UIAutomation tools select a specific element if I provide it some kind of complete path to the element like I find using UIAutomationSpy? I don't really understand why the UIAutomation package seems to search through every UI element in the application just to find 1.

Here is an example of the code I am using that is very slow:

```
#Click on TodayOnly checkbox
Get-UIAWindow -ProcessId ($result).Id -AutomationId $autoID
(Get-UIACheckBox -AutomationID 'TodayOnlyCheckBox').click()#| Invoke-UIACheckBoxToggle

#Sort By User
$header = Get-UIAWindow -ProcessId ($result).Id -AutomationId $autoID | Get-UIAHeader -name 'Users'

$header.Control.Click();

#Click Menu to open new window
Get-UIAWindow -ProcessId ($result).Id -AutomationId $autoID | Get-UIAMenuItem -Name 'Menu' | Invoke-UIAMenuItemClick
```

The $result in this case is the PID. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I found out that by adding -Win32 to the end of the line to click the checkbox, it ran almost instantly like I wanted it. However, the -Win32 doesn't work for the 'Get-UIAHeader' as it fails to find the header element with it there.

Comment: When searching for UIA elements, you can improve performance by restricting the scope of your search (descendants, children, etc.) When using the UIA API directly, this is typically done with the TreeScope enumeration. But in the docs for this PowerShell wrapper, I didn't immediately see a way to adjust the scope of searches. If it doesn't exist in the wrapper, you might need to patch it in, or temporarily fall back to using UIA directly from PowerShell for a particularly slow search.